# Bootstrap "our services" blocks jumping line on medium screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

This problem should be so simple that it is infuriating me. The Bootstrap sections work great except for this medium screen layout, in which one jumps down to the next row... Any suggestions?

[Here is the culprit in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zagWH.png)

In the screenshot the sizes of the left divs are 485x200px and the right divs are both 485x174px. I can provide code if needed, obviously. Just didn't know if this was a common problem with a simple fix.

Thanks!!!

[Here is the code in question on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/n7jtjvFoRB)

Viewport width <1200px to see the problem

Comment: Yes, please provide code. We need to be able to reproduce the issue for ourselves.

Comment: You can receive help here if you can post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior, I assume your code is similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

By dividing it into two rows you should get the desired result:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why does this happen? Bootstraps columns `float: left;`. Your first block is higher than the second block, so your browser tries to fill in the remaining space with the third block.

---

**Sidenote:** When using columns, always add `col-xs-12` unless xs has a different value. (This prevents weird floating behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the help - the problem with this solution is that if I keep the page at full width they now are on two rows instead of all 4 next to each other

Comment: Simple. You're allowed to nest rows into endless depths. **Updated my answer.** Just keep in mind that you're opening a new grid.

Comment: Oh snap! You just taught me some core bootstrap functionality. Never hurts to go back to the basics, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure thing I'm glad I could help :)